# Drawbacks/weaknesses of TDI 1.6 engine in VW Golf Mk 7 (2015)

Tags: engine, tdi

I'm considering to buy an estate VW Golf Mk 7 (2015) with the 1.6 TDI engine. Would you please share the common (well-known) drawbacks or weaknesses of the 1.6 TDI engine, if there are any?

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally the engine is a pretty robust unit - but something to check thoroughly is whether it as affected by the "Dieselgate" scandal, cars that have had the recall "fix" done have significantly poorer driveability and the change to the injection cycle means they chew through EGR valves like there's no tomorrow! And replacing the EGR is not exactly cheap either. If you come across one that's had the recall done - run.

Other than that, as with all modern diesel cars the sort of driving you do is key - if your typical driving consists majorly of short trips, particularly if it's in stop-start traffic then this is going to wreck the DPF in short order.

The Golf VII came with two flavors of the 1.6 TDI - either 90 or 104PS. Honestly I think the 90PS is overtaxed in this application. A modern Golf is not a light car and it's going to be working pretty hard at motorway speeds. The 104 is a much better choice IMO.

Service them properly on-time and with quality consumables and you'll reap the dividends. If you go with the DSG transmission (which is superb by the way) these also need looking after diligently.

Comment: Do you know, how to check if a particular car has been affected by the recall?

Comment: @mabalenk VW have a handy web site to [check](https://www.volkswagen.co.uk/owners/emissionsinfo) from either VIN or reg number.

Comment: Cars subject to the re-call will only rev to 3,000 RPM when stationary and in neutral.  I have a 104PS and in 93,000 miles the only issue I've had was a leaking water pump at around 84,000 miles.  Other than that, service it, use proper 507.00 VW longlife oil and do the timing belt at the right interval and you ought to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

They suffer when not serviced properly.

Comment: All engines suffer when not serviced properly - can you clarify what these ones suffer from that is worse than other similar engines?

Comment: @NickC many cars can have egr problems (and I own one of them...) so why is this car any better than the others? Expecting a list of faults - is that really on-topic?